# Quill editor popUp is being cutoff in the left when we try to add link

Tags: quill

When I try to add link to very left text in quill editor the popUp opened is hiding in the left side.And I am using **Snow** theme.

The below image shows my issue.

[image]

Comment: Can anyone please help with these

Comment: I understand your problem, but I still lack certain information. Could you please demonstrate an image of what is going on? Also, it would be interesting to be able to see your JavaScript code. That way it will be easier to help you. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Loa, I updated my question with image showing the issue. Can you please check it once.

Comment: The image demonstrates exactly what you described. However, Quill's default behavior is not like that, [take a look](https://quilljs.com/playground/#autosave). There is something wrong with __your code__, and I say again, it would be nice to be able to take a look at it. I'll only be able to help you when I can reproduce your problem here...

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution, but you may need to override the css:

```
.ql-tooltip {
  left: 0!important;
}
```

Sometimes quilljs doesn't play nice with theming libraries like certain versions of bootstrap (which was the issue in my case).

Answer (score 1):

If someone encounter this, by default Quill is bound to `document.body`.
On the instance you can use the `bounds` property to define your own container where Quill (tooltip, etc...) will be contained: [Quill documentation](https://quilljs.com/docs/configuration/#bounds)